# Me pide crear una lista con los 10 primeros multiplos IMPARES del numero introducido

Tags: python

No sé como hacer para que solo me salgan los múltiplos impares, esto es lo que he realizado:

```
a = int(input('Escribe un número impar'))
b = list(range(a, a * 11, a))
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seguramente entendí mal la pregunta, pero en base a lo que entendí, esta sería mi solución:

```
a=int(input('escribe un numero impar'))
```

está bien, pedís un número impar, como necesitas los 10 primeros múltiplos también impares se debe multiplicar por otro impar desde el 3 al 21 eso dará todos impares ya que multiplicar por un par dará par, entonces

```
b=[] #creo la lista
for x in range(3,22,2): #un ciclo que devolverá solos los primeros 10 impares 
   b.append(a*x) # los agregamos a la lista
   
print(b)
```

o con comprensión de listas que me parece es lo más parecido a lo que intentaste

```
c=[a*x for x in range(3,22,2)]
print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Para este ejercicio puedes utilizar un ciclo `for` que recorra los múltiplos del número ingresado (entrada).

Se usa el condicional `if` para evaluar si el múltiplo es par o impar. Para esto se utiliza el operador modulo % que retorna el residuo de una división, si hay residuo al dividir el múltiplo entre dos (2) entonces el número es impar y será agregado a la lista multiplos_impares.

Se utiliza otro condicional `if` para evaluar el tamaño de la lista. Si la lista cuenta con 10 elementos entonces se ejecuta el `break` y termina el ciclo `for`.

```
  entrada = int(input('Escribe un número: '))
  multiplos_impares:list = [] 

  for i in range(1, 100):
    if i*entrada % 2 != 0:
      multiplos_impares.append(i*entrada)
    if len(multiplos_impares) == 10:
      break

  print(multiplos_impares)
```